# React app with axios inside useEffect() is rendering twice

Tags: axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I've been trying to figure out why my function that draws a BPMN diagram is rendering the diagram twice. I have looked at various examples using axios inside useEffect but cannot figure out why it is happening. The url is returning a valid xml for the viewer.

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Here is the entire function

```
function RenderBPMN(pathDefinition) {
  const [diagram, setDiagram] = useState(""); 
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const msg = JSON.stringify(pathDefinition);
  const url = `http://localhost:9090/xml?path=${msg}`;
  
  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          axios
          .get(url)
          .then((resp) => {
            setDiagram(resp.data);
          })
          .catch ((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
      fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  if (diagram.length > 0) {
    const viewer = new Viewer({
      container,
      keyboard: {
        bindTo: document
      }
    });
    viewer
      .importXML(diagram)
      .then(({ warnings }) => {
        if (warnings.length) {
          console.log("Warnings", warnings);
        }
        viewer.get('canvas').zoom('fit-viewport');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error", err.message);
      }); 
  }

  return (
      <div
        id="container"
        style={{
          border: "1px solid #010101",
          height: "50vh",
          width: "70vw",
          margin: "auto"
        }}
      ></div>
  );
}
      
export default RenderBPMN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **url** from useEffect array. With empty array it will by called only once when component will be mounted.

```js
useEffect( () => {
    // your code
}, [ /* empty */ ])
```

Comment: Thanks but it still renders twice & I get a warning: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'url'. Either include it or remove the dependency array"

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I read it once about similar behavior which is correlated with ```React.StrictMode``` in development env .. try to build your project and check if work better on production..